# standard library already defined in lib, causing linker error

Tags: c++, linker, lnk2005

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but say I have:

**foo.h**

```
class foo
{
public:
int Get10(std::wstring);
};
```

**foo.cpp**

```
int foo::Get10(std::wstring dir)
{
   return 10;
};
```

And I compile it as a lib, if I include that lib in another project along with the relevant header (foo.h) and atttempt to call an instance of foo:

```
foo f;
f.Get10(L"ABC");
```

I get a linker error saying:

> Error 1   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall
>   std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)"
>   (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in
>   foo.lib(foo.obj)  C:\foo\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)  footest

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Did you try to add semicolon `;` after the class definition?

Comment: yep that's there in the source file haha, my bad for leaving it out of what I put here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Error 1 error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall
>   std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)"
>   (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in foo.lib(foo.obj)
>   C:\foo\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) footest

From what I can see, this error message means that you are trying to include MSVC runtime library twice. This could be due to the result of compiling the `foo.lib` with the Runtime library option: "Multi-threaded (/MT)" and the test project with the option: "Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)" for example.

Check the Runtime options under "Project Properties" ==> "C/C++" ==> "Code Generation" for both projects and make sure they are the same for both projects.

Comment: "with the Runtime library option: Multi-threaded (/MT) and the test project with the option: Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) for example." bingo, that was exactly it (came here to post that)

Comment: I have experienced the same problem before so I knew what is going on when you posted that error :)

Comment: This other question is related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917592/compiling-and-using-jsoncpp-on-visual-studio10-with-boost

Comment: Man sometimes C++ error messages blow my mind at how ambiguous they are.  This is why I use C# for my main code base and C++ for components only.

Comment: @ksming I have these settings and the error. But how do I change them in the Visual Studio GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including foo.h in any .h files? You may need to add header guards to make sure you do not define the class more than once per file:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

class foo
{
 public:
  int Get10(std::wstring);
}

#endif  // FOO_H_
```

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Can you include the entire source of all the functions you are using and the command line then?